# what does it mean that the variable file must contain the base64 of the xml file?

Tags: xml, base64

what does it mean that the variable file must contain the base64 of the xml file?

I have to send an xml file via rest. The documentation tells me that: The file will have to be sent via a POST variable named filename (with base64 encoding).

Any tips?
I tried to convert the xml file to base64 and it generates a .txt file for me but I don't know what to do with it.
I want to test everything with postman right now

Comment: Base64 usually refers to a Base64 string which is packing.  It used to be called UUEncode  in Unix operating systems.  Using c# you would use Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])

Comment: @jdweng: I believe your helpful comment is worthy of being an answer.

Comment: I think this comment doesn't help me